# eOS 5.1 on new machine WIFI only works after suspend

Tags: release-hera, networking

I just bought a cheapo Chuwi Herobook Pro that has Win10 pre-installed. set up eOS 5.1 on dual boot, all works but for wifi. My machines wifi is a Realtek rtl8723be which has known issues with Linux. Apparently it has two antenna slots but only one antenna connected, so sitting right next to the router I could see the router with one bar, but could not connect.
After trying all the fixes I could find I still had no wifi, so I closed the lid and left it be. Coming back later and logging in after suspend I had full wifi. So to test I shut down and restarted, and once again no wifi. Instead of closing the lid I just used the suspend option and the logged back in.
Sure enough, wifi is working. So now I have to boot up, log in, suspend out, log back in and I have wifi.
Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is a way to force antenna selection for that driver.

Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058379/wifi-signal-is-weak-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-rtl8723be) post: